# Adding a Arrow mark to a Border through CSS

Tags: css

this is my CSS of a DIV Tag  for a Marker /ToolTip .

```
<div class="flotr-mouse-value">
position:absolute; 
z-index:1;
background: #FFD772;
height: 75px;
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #666;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #666;
position: absolute;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #666;
left: 50px;top: 50px;
width: 150px;
height: 80px;
</div>
```

Waht i want is that , to have a down arrow at the bottom of the border similar to as shown here 
http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=fa381ec

I have tried modifying the below attribute , but of no use

**border-bottom:**

Comment: It's an image, positioned beneath the box.

Comment: I'm confused by your snippet... it looks like a set of CSS style values but included as text inside an HTML <div> tag, quite out of place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make a triangle by using code like:

```
border-color: #ff0 transparent transparent transparent;
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Here's the code for that example http://jsfiddle.net/hyH48/

There are a lot of limitations (for isntance the box shadow won't work for the triangle), but it doesn't use any images, and is pure CSS.

Comment: Your code works absolutely great , but dont know how to integrate with my Application , as i am using FLotr.js file and in it there is a div  dynamically var mt = this.mouseTrack || this.el.select(".flotr-mouse-value")[0], , and i dont know how to mintegrate the another div with this ??

Comment: I don't know – I haven't used flot.

Answer (score 3):

I used @RichBradshaw's answer but elaborated on it. While he's correct in that it's not possible (or at least very difficult) to add a shadow to the arrow, I achieved the effect by utilizing the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements. Use Rich's code within a `:after` selector, and then in the `:before` selector, create the same arrow, offset in the direction you want your shadow, with a transparent color.

Here is an example! [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WxujE/1/)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do it from css check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/Hec3t/2/)

arrow with border on it:

```
.arrow{
     height: 20px;
     width: 20px;
     margin-left:30px;
    margin-top:-11px;
    background:red;
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    border-right:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```